# swing gui to return user input

Tags: swing

I wrote a small swing program to get user input (a sequence of 0/1 chars, followed by "Done") are return the string to the main class - code attached below. The problem is that it hangs when run in normal mode, but works fine when a breakpoint is put on the "return new String(str)" line (in function getData()), and single-step after that. I figured that it is a timing problem, and put in a "Thread.sleep(400)" before the while-loop (see commented lines) - and now it works fine.

But this code looks stupid. Is there a better way to write this code - to take user input and return the user-given string to the calling class?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class DataEntryPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JButton Button0, Button1, ButtonDone;
    private JLabel DataEntered;
    public char[] str = "________".toCharArray();
    int posn = 0;
    public boolean dataDone = false;
    public DataEntryPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        Button0 = new JButton("0"); Button0.addActionListener(this); this.add(Button0);
        Button1 = new JButton("1"); Button1.addActionListener(this); this.add(Button1);
        ButtonDone = new JButton("Done"); ButtonDone.addActionListener(this); this.add(ButtonDone);
        DataEntered = new JLabel("xxxxxxxx"); this.add(DataEntered);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source  = e.getSource();
        if(source==Button0) DataEntered.setText(setData('0'));
        else if(source==Button1) DataEntered.setText(setData('1'));
        else if(source==ButtonDone) dataDone=true;
    }
    public String setData(char c) {
        if(posn<8) str[posn++] = c;
        return new String(str);
    }
}
class DataEntryFrame extends JFrame {
    public JPanel panel;
    private void centerWindow (Window w) {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
        setLocation((d.width-w.getWidth())/2, (d.height-w.getHeight())/2);
    }
    public DataEntryFrame() {
        setTitle("Data Entry");
        setSize(267, 200);
        centerWindow(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new DataEntryPanel();
        this.add(panel);
    }
    public String getData() {
        DataEntryPanel p = (DataEntryPanel) panel;
        System.out.printf("waiting for data......\n");
        // try {
           while(!p.dataDone) 
                // Thread.sleep(400)
                ; // looping on data completion
        // } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return new String(p.str);
    }
}

public class FRead {
    public FRead() {
        JFrame frame  = new DataEntryFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        DataEntryFrame f = (DataEntryFrame) frame;
        String s = f.getData();
        System.out.printf("string obtained=%s\n", s);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new FRead();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into EDT-issues and eating up your CPU with your while-loop.

1. Everything related to the UI should be performed on the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread)
2. To center a frame, set its size (using `pack()` or `setSize()`) and then simply call `setLocationRelativeTo(null);`
3. Never do a `while(!true) ;` loop, this will eat up your CPU and block the current Thread.
4. Your `dataDone` variable should be declared `volatile` because you are reading it within the "Main" Thread but it is modified by the EDT.

Consider reading about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Here is a slightly modified version of your code that seems to work a lot better:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI {

    class DataEntryPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        private JButton button0, button1, buttonDone;
        private JLabel dataEntered;
        public char[] str = "________".toCharArray();
        int posn = 0;
        public volatile boolean dataDone = false;
        private String data;

        public DataEntryPanel() {
            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            button0 = new JButton("0");
            button0.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(button0);
            button1 = new JButton("1");
            button1.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(button1);
            buttonDone = new JButton("Done");
            buttonDone.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(buttonDone);
            dataEntered = new JLabel("xxxxxxxx");
            this.add(dataEntered);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source == button0) {
                dataEntered.setText(setData('0'));
            } else if (source == button1) {
                dataEntered.setText(setData('1'));
            } else if (source == buttonDone) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data entered is " + String.format("string obtained=%s\n", getData()));
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public String setData(char c) {
            if (posn < 8) {
                str[posn++] = c;
            }
            return data = new String(str);
        }

    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Data Entry");
        frame.setSize(267, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        DataEntryPanel panel = new DataEntryPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reorganizing my code. But you are exiting GUI after getting the data, so it doesnt answer my original question - I want the data to be transfered to the main class. So I need (if I dont use modal dialogs) to poll buttonDone using Thread.sleep. (Or is there any other way to transfer this data to the main class?) I tried making this change, with the SwingUtilities.invokeLater in the main class, and then I could not access the GUI data from main (compilation error: cannot refer to a non-final variable inside inner class defined in a different method).

Comment: @Rog you can add the `final` modifier on a variable if you want. to access it from an inner-class (error message is quite explanitory) Why does your Main needs to access the data? What is preventing you from doing something else than exiting the application when the button "Done" is pressed?

Comment: I might have multiple GUI windows, and one central class doing the processing after collecting data from the different GUIs. So it would be neater if the GUIs just do the data collection and not the processing after that.

Comment: @Rog yes, but that is the role of a Controller class which should create the GUI's and listen for changes/actions in the views. Here my example is simplified so that it is all done in a single class, but you can easily split the different parts to have a clean MVC. Also, rather than having multiple windows, consider using multiple panels, possibly in different tabs, ...

Answer (score 1):

One option would be that you use modal dialogs. Once you open the modal dialog, the code after that will execute only after you close it. Once closed, you can call a getter method on the dialog class from the outside, in order to get the entered values.